# Identify Nouns using Quanteda Corpuses

Tags: r, spacy, quanteda

I am using the quanteda package by Ken Benoit and Paul Nulty to work with textual data.

My corpus contains texts with full German sentences and I want to work with the nouns of every text only. One trick in German is to use the upper case words only, but this would fail at the beginning of a sentence.

```
Text1 <- c("Halle an der Saale ist die grünste Stadt Deutschlands")
Text2 <- c("In Hamburg regnet es immer, das ist also so wie in London.")
Text3 <- c("James Bond trinkt am liebsten Martini")

myCorpus <- corpus(c(Text1, Text2, Text3))
metadoc(myCorpus, "language") <- "german"
summary(myCorpus, showmeta = T)

myDfm <- dfm(myCorpus,  tolower = F, remove_numbers = T, 
                remove = stopwords("german"), remove_punct = TRUE, 
                    remove_separators = T)

topfeatures(myDfm, 20)
```

From this minimal example, I would like to retrieve:
"Halle", "Saale", "Stadt", "Deutschland", "Hamburg", "London", "Martini", "James", "Bond".

I assume I need a dictionary, which defines verbs/nouns/etc. and the proper names (James Bond, Hamburg etc.), or is there a build in function/dict?

Bonus Question: Does the solution work for English texts too?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need some help from a part-of-speech tagger.  Fortunately there is a great one, with a German language model, in the form of [spaCy](http://spacy.io), and a package we wrote as a wrapper around it, **spacyr**.  Installation instructions are at the [**spacyr** page](http://github.com/kbenoit/spacyr).

This code will do what you want:

```
txt <- c("Halle an der Saale ist die grünste Stadt Deutschlands",
         "In Hamburg regnet es immer, das ist also so wie in London.",
         "James Bond trinkt am liebsten Martini")

library("spacyr")
spacy_initialize(model = "de")
txtparsed <- spacy_parse(txt, tag = TRUE, pos = TRUE)

head(txtparsed, 20)
#    doc_id sentence_id token_id        token        lemma   pos   tag entity
# 1   text1           1        1        Halle        halle PROPN    NE  LOC_B
# 2   text1           1        1           an           an   ADP  APPR  LOC_I
# 3   text1           1        1          der          der   DET   ART  LOC_I
# 4   text1           1        1        Saale        saale PROPN    NE  LOC_I
# 5   text1           1        1          ist          ist   AUX VAFIN       
# 6   text1           1        1          die          die   DET   ART       
# 7   text1           1        1      grünste      grünste   ADJ  ADJA       
# 8   text1           1        1        Stadt        stadt  NOUN    NN       
# 9   text1           1        1 Deutschlands deutschlands PROPN    NE  LOC_B
# 10  text2           1        1           In           in   ADP  APPR       
# 11  text2           1        1      Hamburg      hamburg PROPN    NE  LOC_B
# 12  text2           1        1       regnet       regnet  VERB VVFIN       
# 13  text2           1        1           es           es  PRON  PPER       
# 14  text2           1        1        immer        immer   ADV   ADV       
# 15  text2           1        1            ,            , PUNCT    $,       
# 16  text2           1        1          das          das  PRON   PDS       
# 17  text2           1        1          ist          ist   AUX VAFIN       
# 18  text2           1        1         also         also   ADV   ADV       
# 19  text2           1        1           so           so   ADV   ADV       
# 20  text2           1        1          wie          wie  CONJ KOKOM    

(nouns <- with(txtparsed, subset(token, pos == "NOUN")))
# [1] "Stadt"
(propernouns <- with(txtparsed, subset(token, pos == "PROPN")))
# [1] "Halle"        "Saale"        "Deutschlands" "Hamburg"      "London"      
# [6] "James"        "Bond"         "Martini"
```

Here, you can see that the nouns you wanted are marked in the simpler `pos` field as "proper nouns".  The `tag` field is a more detailed, German-language tagset that you could also select from.

The lists of selected nouns can then be used in **quanteda**:

```
library("quanteda")
myDfm <- dfm(txt,  tolower = FALSE, remove_numbers = TRUE, 
             remove = stopwords("german"), remove_punct = TRUE)

head(myDfm)
# Document-feature matrix of: 3 documents, 14 features (66.7% sparse).
# (showing first 3 documents and first 6 features)
#        features
# docs    Halle Saale grünste Stadt Deutschlands Hamburg
#   text1     1     1       1     1            1       0
#   text2     0     0       0     0            0       1
#   text3     0     0       0     0            0       0

head(dfm_select(myDfm, pattern = propernouns))
# Document-feature matrix of: 3 documents, 8 features (66.7% sparse).
# (showing first 3 documents and first 6 features)
#        features
# docs    Halle Saale Deutschlands Hamburg London James
#   text1     1     1            1       0      0     0
#   text2     0     0            0       1      1     0
#   text3     0     0            0       0      0     1
```